# Does a local max that is not strict imply a function is constant in some interval?

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

I have the following question. Thanks for any help in advance. Any hints would be appreciated.

> Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a local max at x that is not a strict local maximum. Is it necessarily true that f is constant in some non-empty open interval (a,b)?

My first thought was to find a counterexample. I wanted to use the Dirichlet function as a counterexample, but that would not work here. It should be noted that the function is not necessarily differentiable.

Comment: What's wrong with the Dirichlet function ?

Comment: A local max at any of the rationals is a strict local max, isn't it?

Comment: No, for any $r\in \mathbb Q$, $f(r)=1$ hence $r$ is a global (hence local) maximum. But for any $\epsilon$, $(r-\epsilon, r+\epsilon)\setminus\{r\}$ contains another rational $r'\neq r$, so $f(r')=1$. $r$ is not a strict local max.

Comment: You're right. This is a little embarrassing, since a valid counterexample is ruled out in the body of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct also a differentiable function with these properties:
$$
f(x) :=
\begin{cases}
x^2 ( 1 - \sin\frac{1}{x}), & \text{if}\ x\neq 0,\\
0, & \text{if}\ x = 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Since OP considers maxima, you might want to consider $-f$ instead.

Comment: This function has a local maximum at $x=0$.